# jQuery Overlay not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, overlay

Appologies if this has been answered elsewhere, but I couldn't find anything.

I am working with [jQueryTools Overlay](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/).
Working fine in chrome, but in IE-8 i have this issue that my overlaying Div pops up like a normal div, at the top of my form.

heres the html:

```
<div id="overlay" >
        <img src="http://www.sanbaldo.com/wordpress/wp-content/bigrotation2.gif" class="img-load" />
    </div>
```

heres the CSS:

```
#overlay
{
    background: #DCDCDC;
    border: 5px solid #666;
    display: none;
    height: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    width: 50%;
}
.img-load
{
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(".button_small").click(function () {
    $("#overlay").overlay().load();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that IE8 is now adhering to standards and this gives problems with plugins trying to circumvent the pre IE8 problems.

One possible solution is to force IE9 in IE8 standards mode with this meta tag:

the other option is to fix the code:

most UI plugins reside on $.browser.msie to check if we are in IE but they don't check the version. In my case the solution (jquery.ui.checkbox.js) was to replace all $.browser.msie calls with this variable :

```
var isIEAndVersionIsLowerThan8 = $.browser.msie && (parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 8);
```

This solution is better than adding the meta tag as it will enable all IE8 features.

Comment: sorry, i dont get it, where should i use this variable and how?